# Python IndexError: too many indices

Tags: python, indexing, runtime-error, indices

I already searched for similar questions but I couldn't find a solution. In front I have no idea from Python. I just got a script which should work theoretically and plot me a graph with some point data but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\***\create_plot.py", line 38, in <module>
formatter.create_plot()
File "C:\***\CPI_Plotter.py", line 54, in create_plot
plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], styles[name[0]%7], label=name[1])
IndexError: too many indices
```

The appropriate code is here:

```
def create_plot(self):
    """
        Plot the different data sets 
    """
    styles = ['o', 's', '^', 'v', 'D', '1', '+']

    for name, line in zip(enumerate(self.labels), self.plot_data):
        if name[1][-4:] == '.csv':
            plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], label='XNS Simulation')
            styles.insert(name[0],'')
        else:
            plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], styles[name[0]%7], label=name[1])
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use commas in slicing in python. What this string supposed to do?

```
plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], label='XNS Simulation')
```

Comment: As far as I understand the code, this should name the graph and the different point data shown in the plot.

Comment: can you show example of self.labels and self.plot_data?

Comment: I've done some tests and the script is working fine on Mac OS. So it has to be an error with windows or more precisely something in the script doesn't work on winows. Maybe it has to do with the filesystem on windows?!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Like already said I think it was an problem with the windows filesystem or something like that. On Mac OS it worked fine.
To run on a windows machine, I changed the following command

```
infile = open(filepath, "r")
```

into

```
infile = open(filepath, "rb")
```

On this way, the input file/files is opened in binary mode and the script runs normally.